# Custom error detection IntelliSense in C#

Tags: c#

I have some code

```cs
entity.Add(itemBeingDependedOn);
entity.Add(itemWithDependency);
```

In the situation where line one is not there, I want to give the developer a red squiggly saying that it will fail rather than just throwing a runtime exception when it does.

I am curious if this is possible to implement or if I would just have to write a custom parser to write this functionality.

Comment: You might research Roslyn Code Analyzers.

Comment: I think that might actually be what I am looking for, I will update this question after some research